# Can' deploy my WebSocket Java app on Heroku

Tags: java, git, heroku, deployment

Hi there) I'm getting started with Java EE and I've made my websocket server endpoint according to [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/) example (except for i use **tomcat** instead of **glassfish**)

I've created heroku app with `heroku create`. Then executed:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

in my netbeans project root, but when i do this:

```
git push heroku master
```

i receive this

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !   Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote:  !   Push rejected to guarded-reaches-2466.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/guarded-reached-2466.git
 ! [remote-rejected] master->master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/guarded-reached-2466.git'
```

any ideas, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that Heroku could not find an appropriate buildpack for your application. For the Java buildpack, the detection scripts requires that a `pom.xml` file be present in the root directory of your project (and it must be checked into Git). Is the case?